# Slicing strings backwards by index

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

I have a string that looks like this:

```
((id = id_2) AND (condition1 = condition2))
```

What I want is to get the string that ends with the first ')' and backwards until the associated '('. Then I use that string and replace it with something else. This way I can repeat the operation until I get a string that has no '(' or ')'.
So far, my code is something like this:

```
original_string = '((id = id_2) AND (condition1 = condition2))'
while ')' in original_string:
    needed_string = original_string[original_string.index(')'):original_string.index('('):-1][::-1]
    original_string.replace(needed_string, 'False')
```

That works and after the first iteration I get what I want:

```
needed_string = '(id = id_2)'
original_string = '(False AND (condition1 = condition2))'
```

But in the next iteration, I get:

```
needed_string = 'False AND (condition1 = condition2)'
```

What I want for the second iteration is:

```
needed_string = '(condition1 = condition2)'
```

So that after I use replace, original_string looks like this:

```
original_string = '(False AND False)'
```

This way, during the 3rd iteration:

```
needed_string = '(False and False)'
```

and after replacing,

```
original_string = 'False'
```

I am new to python so I'm not sure if this is OK or if there's a better way to be doing this, but it has to be done in a simple way (without using any 3rd party libraries) or tokenizing

Comment: If you're lazy, https://sexpdata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Forgot to mention that it has to be done without using any 3rd party libraries

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the desired output for each iteration, so we know how your code is intended to work.

Comment: Done. I hope its easier to understand now.

Comment: Based on the syntax you have, you should probably be tokenizing in some way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to find and replace all of the needed values.

```
import re
def get_groups(expr, replace):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\([^()]*\)')
    while True:
        m = pattern.search(expr)
        if m is None:
            break
        expr = expr[:m.start()] + replace + expr[m.end():]
        yield (m.group(), expr)
```

and use this method as such:

```
>>> expr = '((id = id_2) AND (condition1 = condition2))'
>>> for needed_string, original_string in get_groups(expr, 'False'):
        print('needed string   =', repr(needed_string))
        print('original string =', repr(original_string))
        print()

needed string   = '(id = id_2)'
original string = '(False AND (condition1 = condition2))'

needed string   = '(condition1 = condition2)'
original string = '(False AND False)'

needed string   = '(False AND False)'
original string = 'False'
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that you find *first* left parenthesis not the corresponding one to right parenthesis you found before.

To solve this problem you can use regular expression as [Kupiakos suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014581/slicing-strings-backwards-by-index/37015228#37015228) or you can try to use [str.rfind](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind) method

```
  def replace_first_expression(string, replacement):
      close_parenthesis_pos = string.find(')')
      if close_parenthesis_pos == -1:
          return string
      open_parenthesis_pos = string.rfind('(', 0, close_parenthesis_pos)
      if open_parenthesis_pos == -1:
          return string
      return string[:open_parenthesis_pos] + replacement + string[close_parenthesis_pos + 1:]
```